# Hexadecimal String to Int conversion

Tags: sml

I have a hexadecimal string like `"0xff"`, and want to convert it to int, which is 255.

But `Int.fromString "0xff"` gives the answer `0`.

I though that `Int.scan` would help. But I'm new to SML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
StringCvt.scanString (Int.scan StringCvt.HEX) "0xff"
```

or

```
StringCvt.scanString (Int.scan StringCvt.HEX) "ff"
```